# LaTeX beamer package, colortheme “dolphin”: Frametitles are not displayed?

Tags: beamer

I want to use the LaTeX beamer package with the colortheme “dolphin” as it looks really nice, especially in combination with the outertheme “miniframes“. But using the said colortheme won’t display any frame titles. Minimal example follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Oh no, I am not displayed}
Some letters to fill the slide up
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

How can I get the titles displayed?

Comment: I get the frame title. You should be using `\usetheme{shadow}` rather than `\usepackage`, but the result is the same, for me. What TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: I use Ubuntu 12.04 and have the texlive package installed. `\usetheme{shadow}` gives the same output and evince fails to display the title in the same way.

Comment: I guess the `\usetheme{shadow}` was a good idea. When I do 
`    \documentclass{beamer}    
    
    \useoutertheme{shadow}
    \useoutertheme{miniframes}
    \usecolortheme{dolphin}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \section{Great, a section}
    \subsection{Even greater, a subsection}
    \begin{frame}{Oh no, I am not displayed}
    Some letters to fill the slide up
    \end{frame} 
    
    \end{document}`

I get what I wanted in the first place and the result is properly displayed by evince.

Nonetheless it bugs me a little that evince is failing here.

Answer (score 6):

I think this could even be a problem of your pdf-viewer.

For example, this code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}    

\useoutertheme{shadow}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Oh no, I am not displayed}
Some letters to fill the slide up
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

seen with Evince gives:

[image]

while with Okular:

[image]

Comment: This is interesting. Xournal and evince won't display them, but inkscape does. Is this a known bug? What causes this issue to be?

Comment: I remember having read that evince has problems to display some fonts. I tried to change the fonts via \usefonttheme but it didn't help.

Comment: It's the first time also for me that I see this kind of behavior so I don't know the reason behind. I've noticed that, with Evince, the title is there (you can highlighted it), but it is behind the shadow.

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't think of this. So it's not a font related problem. I really don't know how to google this...

Comment: Yes, my opinion is that the issue is not related with the font, but with the shadow although I've no idea how to fix it.